# Starting new Angular application in new Browser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web application that I need to open a new browser window from and load an angular application into it. I Dont see any problems with that by dong the following:

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures]);
```

After getting a reference to a new window I can call its function and send data to it. Sending data is the critical function. I am a bit fuzzy however how exactly Angular app will be getting this data. Will I be able to call a $rootScope function using windowObjectReference?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Need to elaborate on what you are wanting to do

Answer (score 0):

I would use whatever backend api you are using for your web app to pass the data instead. That way, your angular app should be set up to use the http library that's built in to request that data from there on load. That way you have a lot more angular constructs that can help you along the way. An example of the code in your angular app would look like this:

```
var onGetResponse = function(data) {
    $scope.appData = data;
}
var onGetError = function(reason) {
    $scope.responseError = "Could not get the app data.";
    alert($scope.responseError);
}

$http.get('/appData').success(onGetResponse).error(onGetError);
```

The bottom statement actually makes the call to your backend api and when it gets a successful response, it will call the top. Then your angular app can access the information with {{appData}}.

Comment: No, I cannot use bqckend, at least for now. It has to be a client solution only.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry then. Maybe if you described your limitations a bit more I could think of a better fitting solution. Right now the only other suggestion I have is just adding a reference to angular in the web application itself. Then you could use whatever server side language you are using to assign the data to some $scope object. That way, you can just open the new url and the angular part will already know about your data.

Comment: Sure, I need to open a new browser window from current application and load Angular app into it. As I said, that part is easy. I also need to transfer some user specific data into that new application from the first application.

Comment: And these two applications are completely different? Because if they are in the same code base and both under your control, I would suggest using angular in the starting web page (even if only to assign the data to a $scope object). That way angular can keep up with the data on its own when you open the new url in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

There are many method by which a window can talk with a window, from the same domain, it opened:

- [Shared Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) and [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) can communicate with all windows from the same domain.
- With [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) you can send a receive messages from
  opened windows, and iFrames.
- [`Local storage`](http://ponyfoo.com/articles/cross-tab-communication) can be used for communications between windows
  from the same domain, using the `storage` event that is fired when a key content is changed.
- The old method is using [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener). The opened window can
  refer to  it's parent and request the information it needs. The
  parent just have to store an object on the window with the needed
  methods.
- You can also send information via the url using the hash # part.

You can encapsulate most of this methods in a service on both the opened an window and the opener. btw - don't forget $apply with any of this methods.